# What do I see the GPS icon consistently?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I've written my custom location manager to check for an update in the user's location every 30 seconds. The code is working fine i.e. I'm receiving updates in user's location. But the problem is that the GPS icon is always visible on the status bar on top. I'm guessing that it should be visible only once in 30 seconds. Is this normal or I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

```
public volatile Double mLatitude = 0.0;
public volatile Double mLongitude = 0.0;

int minTime = 30000;
float minDistance = 0;
MyLocationListener myLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);

String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, myLocListener, null);     
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, minTime, minDistance, myLocListener);


private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            if (loc != null) {
                //Do something knowing the location changed by the distance you requested
                mLatitude = loc.getLatitude();
                mLongitude = loc.getLongitude();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location Changed! "+Double.toString(mLatitude)+" "+Double.toString(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0)
        {
            //Do something here if you would like to know when the provider is disabled by the user
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Provider Disabled! "+Double.toString(mLatitude)+" "+Double.toString(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0)
        {
            //Do something here if you would like to know when the provider is enabled by the user
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Provider Enabled! "+Double.toString(mLatitude)+" "+Double.toString(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2)
        {
            //Do something here if you would like to know when the provider status changes
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Provider Status Changed! "+Double.toString(mLatitude)+" "+Double.toString(mLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is old but still, it would be great to give a better answer.

You need to use a `Handler` which runs continuously on 5 minutes interval so, you get the location update only once and you release the GPS device, this way your app won't listen to the GPS updates but your handler know when it should be called again to listen the updates.

```
public static void getLocation(Context context) {

    Handler locationHandler = new Handler();

    locationHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Handle the location update
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            }, null);

            locationHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 60 * 5);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As long as 1 or more apps have called requestLocationUpdates for the GPS provider, GPS will stay on.  It doesn't turn off between requests.  It can't-  doing so would cause it to lose satellite lock, which would cause it to have to re-establish.  That takes a lot more than 30 seconds sometimes.  So GPS will stay on until you unregister for GPS events.

Comment: What if I change the interval to maybe 10 minutes? Will the GPS icon vanish in that case and reappear after 10 minutes?

If not, then maybe I should start a runnable which requests a requestSingleUpdate after every 10 minutes?

Comment: No.  Because you're still requesting updates.  If you really want it to disappear that badly, you'd need to stop requesting updates and re-request them later.  But expect it to take a minute or two to get a signal after you request it, and for it to take another minute or so after that for the signal to become accurate.  During which time the symbol would be shown.  Why are you so concerned about it?  Unless you're trying to hide the fact you're asking for location it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: I don't want to waste the user's battery. I want his "accurate" location but the frequency is not important. A 5-10 minute frequency is okay with me. What would be the best strategy?

Comment: Then the best thing to do is request a single update, then set a timer when you get it via alarm manager. When the alarm goes off, request another. Repeat.

Comment: Thanks. This almost answers my question. Just the last question now. Isn't Handler better than AlarmManager here? Since I need the user's location only when he's actually using the app.

Comment: Depends-  do you need the data if the phone goes to sleep with the app running?  If so, alarms are better (handlers won't run).

Comment: Nope. I need data only when the app is running.